# Specifying a file extension in C

Tags: c, file-io

For my project I am getting a file name from the user and sending it to a function to create the actual file/open it if it already exists. The problem i am having is that when the compiler creates the file...it is literally just that, a file. How can i specify a file type after receiving the name via command line?

from main:

```
printf("Enter the name of the file in which you wish to create\nor if you know the name of an exisiting file, enter that file name:\n");
scanf(" %s", FNAME);
File = FileOpen(FNAME);
```

the function:

```
FILE *FileOpen(char* FNAME) {
FILE* pFile;
pFile = fopen(FNAME,"rb+");
if (!pFile)
  pFile = fopen(FNAME,"wb+");
return pFile;
```

Comment: "It is literally just that, a file." As opposed to a what? I don't understand the problem here.

Comment: What do you mean by "type"?

Comment: from the statements that you provided, it can be seen that you are accepting the file from scanf statement. in question you are saying that the file name is accepted from command line. totally confusing.

Comment: What do you mean "literally just that, a file"? What do you expect it to be instead? `FileOpen` opens a **file**, just as it says in its name.

Comment: You're leaking a `FILE *` in `FileOpen`; the second `fopen` loses the pointer returned by the first.

Comment: What you will need to do is check `FNAME` to see if it includes an extension. There is no standard way, but `strchr` (or `strrchr`) are good starting points. If it contains an extension -- use it. If no extension is found, then you will need to provide a default extension of your choosing. `strcat` likewise is a good starting point.

Comment: For added fun, see what happens when entering a folder name... (I.e., do *not* trust your code to always return a valid file handle.)

Comment: I like the idea David, i might put that in later. For now i just added a bit to the text that states not to include an extension

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i ended up doing after some digging around/help from a friend.

```
sprintf(FNAME, "%s%s", FNAME, ".dat");
```

thanks for all the replies

Answer (score 0):

try this :

pFile = fopen("path\FNAME.extension","rb+");

here enter the absolute path of the file ,filename along with its extension within the qotes .

path is not necessary if the file is in same directroy !
ex-
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("file.txt","r");

here file.txt is in the same directry as the program file is.

Comment: #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   FILE * fp;

   fp = fopen ("file.txt", "w+");
   fprintf(fp, "%s %s %s %d", "We", "are", "in", 2014);
   
   fclose(fp);
   
   return(0);
}

//this code will create a txt file named file.txt and will contain "We are in 2014

Comment: What question is your answer associated with? It seems to be explaining how to open a file stream. I don't recall that being the problem above. Also - please do not include code in the comments. Edit your answer and include the code in the correct format there. If you do not know how to format the answer, others will help, I'll help, but please read Help on answering questions.

Comment: I thought I had asked a pretty simple question, but I guess not hah. I guess in reality all I was trying to do was get a string from the user and add an extension to the end of the given string and pass that to fopen ()

Answer (score 0):

`#include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
   int main()`
{
   `FILE * fp;`

`fp = fopen ("file.txt", "w+");`

`fprintf(fp, "%s %s %s %d", "We", "are", "in", 2014);`

`fclose(fp);`

`return(0);`
`}`

`//this code will create a txt file named file.txt and will contain "We are in 2014`